# Sorting in table not working when having rows with and without colspan

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a table that shows a list of events, each event also has a detail row that is initially hidden and will become visible by clicking a button.

The markup looks like this:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Header 1</th>
         <th>Header 2</th>
         <th>Header 3</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="i-am-always-visible">
         <td>Event date</td>
         <td>Event name</td>
         <td>Event location</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="3" class="i-am-hidden-by-default">
            Contact form
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the JS I use for setting up my sortable table

```
$('#tableId').dataTable({
   "bPaginate": false,
   "bAutoWidth": false
});
```

No the tricky part comes in: I want to make the table sortable with the jQuery plugin dataTables and it seems like it can't handle rows with a colspan and I couldn't find any configuration option I could pass to dataTables on initialization to handle these rows properly.

Has anyone came across the same issue and solved it or can point me to the right place information regarding this issue is available?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it seems that this is not possible with any library/script I found on the web. Seems like it's a pretty hard task. I ended up using [knockout.js](http://www.knockoutjs.com) to achieve the result I need. It's very SEO unfriendly, so think about twice before using it ;-) In my case this was not needed.

If anyone wants to do the same thing, here's some basic knockout.js code:

```
function myViewModel() {
     var self = this;

     self.data = ko.observableArray([
          {"id":1, "date":"2012/01/01", "name":"bar", "location":"New York City"},
          {"id":2, "date":"2012/01/01", "name":"bar", "location":"New York City"},
          {"id":3, "date":"2012/01/01", "name":"bar", "location":"New York City"}
     ]);

     self.sortData = function() {
          self.data.sort(function(left, right) {
               // ... custom sorting code ...
          });
     }
}
```

**The view**

```
<table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>ID</th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Location</th>
        </tr>           
     </thead>
     <tbody data-bind="foreach: data">
        <tr class="i-am-always-visible">
           <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
           <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
           <td data-bind="text: location"></td>             
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td colspan="3" class="i-am-hidden-by-default">
              Contact form
           </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

**How does it work?**
Usually the scripts that sort HTML tables sort the HTML nodes as they don't know anything about the data source. With knockout.js you sort the data source and it then takes care of redrawing the table rows, no matter how much colspans you have :-)

Hope it also helps somebody else!